# Privileges required in multitenant Architecture of Oracle Database to alter session set container

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, multi-tenant, database-administration, oracle19c

I have a user in Oracle 19C at container level, I want to grant him the privileges to switch among multiple pluggable database through alter session set container command without granting him the sysdba/dba privilege.

Please let me know, if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any administrative role. The SYSDBA, SYSOPER, etc are only necessary if the PDB you're trying to switch to is currently CLOSED.

Otherwise -

```
-- drop user C##_JEFF;
-- USER SQL
CREATE USER C##_JEFF IDENTIFIED BY "oracle" container=all 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";

-- QUOTAS

-- ROLES

-- SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO C##_JEFF container=all;
GRANT SET CONTAINER to C##_JEFF container=all;
```

And then, since you tagged SQLDev -

[image]

In addition to the Docs of course, [Oracle-Base has a nice article on this concept](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1#switching-between-containers). I will say, it's pretty rare that you would actually want COMMON users that could switch into any PDB that were not administrator accounts. Be sure you understand what the CDB is actually for before you jump in. Most applications will have everything they need defined in the pluggable database (PDB).

Comment: OK One last thing I want to ask is... Is there any possibility that a local user can access multiple PDBs. It may be a silly question, but the thing here I need to do is I don't want to use the prefix 'C##' before the username of my user and I want to access multiple PDBs through that user. It will be a great help for me.

Comment: Then you need to create the user, multiple times, in each PDB. And they won't switch containers, they'll just connect directly to each PDB as necessary.